# How to disable suggestions in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

The new Gmail interface has suggestions visible in this image:
[image]

How can I turn them off?

Comment: From the mobile app, under account settings you have (around the middle) Smart Reply checkbox that can be removed. I haven't saw any same-name-looking setting in the web app. Maybe it will work?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have this setting. I think it's because I don't use a smart phone, I only access gmail from a web browser on a computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we saw, at the moment there isn't a builtin way for doing that.

**You can go for other solutions:**

- Block the element with your ad blocker
- Use a user script manager with a small script that will just remove the suggested replies.

  - You can use this:

    ```
    document.querySelector('div[aria-label*="Suggested reply"]').parentNode.remove()
    ```

    [image]

Comment: It seems I didn't need to block the element with ad block or set up a script to remove the replies. 2 weeks have passed since I asked the question above and now the suggestions do not appear any more. Maybe because I didn't use them a single time?

Comment: That's interesting 

Comment: In fact the suggestions where not gone. Using Add block plus, I added a filter for ` .bra`  elements, by clicking on "block element" and clicking on the suggestion text.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there's a setting under the `General` tab called `Writing suggestions off`.

There's also the `Smart Reply` setting. Turning both of those off should turn off any suggestions that Gmail offers.

Source: https://betanews.com/2018/10/07/disable-gmail-smart-compose/

Answer (score 0):

1st and foremost - Go to your Gmail account and click on the settings menu at the top right corner and inside the 
**settings** -> **general** tab -> **smart reply** -> check the button "**Smart reply off**".

That's it! you will never get any suggestions until you enable the button manually.